# SauceLabs Cordova Appium Android Nightwatch test CrossWalk Project Issue

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, appium, nightwatch.js, saucelabs

I am trying to run a Cordova Appium Android Nightwatch test using SauceLabs. I am using `android-armv7-release-unsigned.apk` . Here are my desiredCapabilities configurations

`appiumVersion: '1.5.3',
  deviceName: 'Samsung Galaxy S4 Emulator',
  platformVersion: '4.4',
  platformName: 'Android',
  deviceOrientation: 'portrait',
  app:'sauce-storage:android-armv7-release-unsigned.apk'
  browserName:'',`

I am seeing the following error when the app tries to start up.

`Mismatch of CPU Architecture The Crosswalk
Project Service must be updated to match the CPU architecture of the
device. Please install it from the app store, then restart mfg.`

I am including `cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview@1.7.0` in my `cordova.conf.js` . I have tried upgrading the plugin to `1.8.0` but I'm still getting the same issue.

I have tried many variations of the device + version combinations.

Any help would be great. Thank you!

Comment: APPIUM + Nightwachjs , this stack is slow . And Appium doesnt work well with the elements in most of cordova app,i think you should go to another framework instead appium.

Comment: hmm I've noticed, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The latest Appium works fast for me, even on web apps. It actually uses the latest Android access to elements used in Android Studio. I wrote something up for web testing and was impressed, but a while back it did look really clunky. Here are the steps... http://www.shaneofalltrades.com/2016/08/26/Mobile-Web-Testing-Using-Nightwatchjs-part-2/